# Which auxiliary LaTeX files should be ignored by Version Control Software?

Tags: auxiliary-files, revision-control, git, cross-platform

I'm about to start version controlling my LaTeX documents with Git but I haven't used either very much. I would like to version only the files needed to compile the document but I use different OS's (OSX, Windows and different distros of Linux). I did a search for a `.gitignore` file for LaTeX and came up with 3 different ones:

- https://gist.github.com/149016
- https://gist.github.com/871983 (a fork of the above but for Mac)
- https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/LaTeX.gitignore (another for LaTeX in general)

Here's a comparison of each in alphabetical order in tabular format:

```
*.acn               *.acn               
*.acr               *.acr               
*.alg               *.alg               
*.aux               *.aux               .aux
*.bbl               *.bbl               *.bbl
*.blg               *.blg               *.blg
*.dvi               *.dvi               *.dvi
                                        *.fdb_latexmk
*.glg               *.glg               *.glg
*.glo               *.glo               *.glo
*.gls               *.gls               *.gls
*.idx               *.idx               *.idx
*.ilg               *.ilg               *.ilg
*.ind               *.ind               *.ind
*.ist               *.ist               *.ist
*.lof               *.lof               *.lof
*.log               *.log               *.log
*.lot               *.lot               *.lot
*.maf               *.maf               
                    *.mp                
*.mtc               *.mtc               
*.mtc1              *.mtc1              
                                        *.nav
                                        *.nlo
*.out               *.out               *.out
                    *.pdf               
                                        *.pdfsync
                                        *.snm
*.synctex.gz        *.synctex.gz        *.synctex.gz
                    *.tmp               
*.toc               *.toc               *.toc
                    *.top               
                    *.tui               
                                        *.vrb

                    # Mac IDE files             
                    *.swp               
                    *~              
                    *(Autosaved).rtfd/              
                    Backup[ ]of[ ]*.pages/              
                    Backup[ ]of[ ]*.key/                
                    Backup[ ]of[ ]*.numbers/                

                    # Mac finder files and hidden folders               
                    .DS_Store
```

Can anyone suggest why some might be missing from others and if it's okay just to include them all in one `.gitignore` file for use on all OS's?

Comment: Don't ignore PDF if you have PDF images :)

Comment: For most documents, only *very* few of those will be generated. I just add files to .gitignore when something I didn't create myself (i.e., something other than `.tex`, or images or whatever) is shown by git as untracked. I guess there could be value in a universal .gitignore list, but false positives also mean files could go untracked.

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. This is a great question! I myself use version control software for LaTeX to a great extend and started to collect such lists. Because this also affects other VC software I took the liberty to make the title and tags more general. Also, the house style around here is to not have an opening or closing on posts. Your name automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: Something to remember is that `git clean` won't target files that are listed in `.gitignore` unless `git clean -x` is used.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you very much for your comments. Extremely helpful! It's difficult to choose a single answer to mark as correct so I've chosen the one with the most votes (please don't be offended if it wasn't yours). @Martin: Thanks for editing the tags/title for me.  Right, off to create my repo :)

Comment: in addition to @Sharpie's comment, `git clean -f -X` will remove **only** git-ignored files. useful for cleaning up auxilary files without getting rid of all those extra scrap files that might still be useful. use `git clean -n -X`to see that will be removed without removing it. Tip originally from http://stackoverflow.com/a/64966/210945

Comment: +1 for a really nice *comparison of each in alphabetical order in tabular format* !

Comment: I thought I had all the ones that TeX Live generates, but the other day I found that git had picked up a `.synctex.gz(busy)` file. Yes that's right, the file extension was `.gz(busy)`. So I had to tell it to stop tracking that one and add that to the ignore list.

Comment: @Hammerite You must have used git while compiling your document. Good catch, though.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The reason for an ignore file list is the following.  When your VCS spots a file in the directory that it isn't versioning, it tells you about it (politely).  For example, in one of my directories then running `bzr status`, I get the following message:

```
tex.SE% bzr status
unknown:
  Project/
  braids.sty@
  bzr_test/
  lessonplan.cls@
  lessonplan.sty@
  listings.sty
  mylectures.sty@
  refs.bib
  tqft.sty@
  unicode-math-chg.sty
  unicode_beamer_test.txt
  xepstricks.xdv
```

That's a useful feature to have since it tells me if there are files that I haven't yet put under the control of the VCS.  In particular, if I spot anything with the suffix `.tex` there, then I know that there's something I forgot to do before committing my changes.

The point of the ignore file (`.bzrignore` in my case) is to remove stuff automatically from this list.  If I get rid of that file in this directory then I get a list of **833** files!  That's rather a long list to go through to see if I've missed a `.tex` file or not.

The important things to remember with ignore files are thus:

1. It is more important to focus on what is **not** there than what is there.  The extensions that are not there are the types of files where you think, "It is more than likely that a file of this extension will be under the control of the VCS.".
2. It is **advisory**.  The ignore file simply tells the VCS which files you will usually put under its control.  You are completely free to ignore its recommendations and *not* put under its control a file that it lists, and you are completely free to put under its control a file that it *doesn't* list.
3. It can be **changed**.  It's actually best to start with a minimal file (I'll give an example at the end) and only add extensions as you find that you need them.  As I said, the main purpose of this file is as an early warning system to ensure that everything that should be ignored actually is.  If you import an ignore file from some central repository and then start creating files yourself which happen to have those extensions (just because you wouldn't have thought they could be anything to do with TeX), then you might miss a file.  So when you find the list of suggested files too long to see the important ones in, then add some more extensions to the list.
4. It should be **project-specific**.  The files you want to ignore in one project are not necessarily the same as in another.  You should have a small main list that are safe to *always* ignore, and then add things to it on a per-project basis.
5. It should be **versioned**.  Goes without saying, really!

So what should be in it?  The basic rule is that you should version those files that *you directly create*.  So the things you don't version are those that are created for you (the exception to this is if you don't have a copy of the program that creates them on every machine, gnuplot data files are an example that springs to mind).  So the initial list should be those files that your TeX process creates.  As you say you're using LaTeX, the following is a fairly minimal list:

```
    *.aux
    *.pdf
    *.ps
    *.log
    *.dvi
    *.tex~
```

If you are using BibTeX, add `.bbl` and `.blg` to that list.
If your system has a habit of creating extra files in the system, then add those.  That's what things like `.DS_Store` are doing on those lists.  That's Mac-specific.  Linux doesn't do things like that (it's polite).  I have no idea what Windows does.  As you start using other programs, and more complicated packages, you'll find new files springing in to existence.  If you generate web pages, you'll find yourself wanting to add a whole slew like `.4ct` and similar.

So, in summary, start small and remember that the computer is there to do what *you* tell it to do, not the other way around.

Comment: I'm only getting into `git` now, but this answer is very useful. Thanks! As pointed out by Martin in the comments, though, if you have `pdf` images, you should carefully consider whether to use the `*.pdf` rule or not.

Comment: @Jubobs That comes under Note 2.

Comment: One other note, most of these systems have multiple ignore directive files (`~/.gitignore` plus local `.gitignore`, for instance). Patterns for your own editor's backup files, such as `*~`, will generally belong in your personal "*I* don't version these files" file (`~/.gitignore`), while patterns that apply to "this project uses auxiliary document-builder zorgtex which leaves `*.evil` files" belong in the repository's `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 29):

LaTeX and its packages produce a variety of auxiliary files. There are also some external tools which create their own files. Then there is the set of output files generated by (La)TeX like DVI, PS and PDF files which you may or may not want to put under version control. Normally you don't.

The reason some extension are missing in some lists is because the number of extensions can depend a lot on the packages and tools used. New packages are created all the time and some might not be known or used by the authors of theses lists.

---

I think it would be good to have a list and maybe description of packages and the auxiliary files created by them. Here the ones I just had in my mind (and in my `svn:ignore` lists). A used a category for extensions I couldn't place to a specific package right away.

- (La)TeX: *.log *.aux *.toc
- Lists: *.lof *.lot
- Index: *.idx *.ind *.ilg
- Glossary: *.glo *.gls *.glg
- Bib(La)TeX: *.bbl *.blg
- `hyperref`: *.out
- `svn-multi`: *.svn *.svt *.svx
- `standalone`: *.sta *.stp
- `latexmk` tool: *.fdb_latexmk
- `endfloat`: *.fff
- Other: *.run.xml

Comment: `http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thumbs` creates *.tmb files.

Answer (score 17):

I agree with  ShreevatsaR's comment. For most projects, very few of these are actually generated - it depends what packages you decide to include. So I start off with an empty `.gitignore` and add only the ones that I actually see appearing when I compile my TeX files.

Also, sometimes it's not appropriate to add an extension to the `.gitignore` willy-nilly. For example, if you have PDF images, then you probably don't want to add `*.pdf` to your `.gitignore`, rather you want to add `yourtexfile.pdf`. Similarly if all of your `*.eps` images are automatically generated from something else in your makefile (for example, I use dia for most of my images, and the EPS versions are generated by asking dia to automatically convert the figures), then it's appropriate to add `*.eps`.

Lastly, you can add  exceptions to the `.gitignore` by prepending a line with an `!`. For example, the following will ignore all automatically generated PDF files, while paying attention to `figure.pdf` which is a manually generated PDF image.

```
*.aux
*.dvi
*.pdf
!figure.pdf
```

Comment: Useful to know about exclusions, and good point about the PDFs.

Answer (score 14):

Quite a few modules create their own auxiliary files.

For example, you might also clean:

- `*.lol` (list of listings);
- `*.ps` (if it's not your final format);
- `*.idv` and `*.lg`;
- `*.4tc`, `*.4ct`,  `*.xref` if you use `tex4ht`;

In general, what I do is that I version all my source files. When I use new modules (or new renderers), after cleaning my code with `make clean`, I run a `git status` to check for auxiliary files that I don't know about, and I add them to my `clean` rule (or `.gitignore` if you prefer).