# Deleting external/auxiliary files?

Tags: external-files, auxiliary-files

Is there a way to make TeX delete files?

In my document a lot of auxiliary files are created and it would be wonderful to have them removed after their content has been used.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11123/prevent-pdflatex-from-writing-a-bunch-of-files/11130#11130) about why the files are important, and why you wouldn't want to delete them too often!

Comment: if you store your lxtex files in git, the you can ignore all the auxiliary files with a `.gitignore`, and easily get rid of them with `git clean -x -f`. But check first with `git clean -x -n`!

Comment: You may be interested in the beautiful tool by Paulo Cereda as demonstrated in this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77879/11232. It also has a `clean` utility.

Comment: There is also `arara`: [Is there a way to configure pdflatex to make all but the .tex and .pdf files hidden files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87818)

Answer (score 68):

if you want get rid of those files in your document directory then use the optional argument `-output-directory=whatever`. Then all auxiliary files and the pdf are saved in that directory. For example what I use:

```
pdflatex -output-directory=target <file>
```

then my `<file>.pdf` is also in `target`, but I always use a softlink `ln -s target/<file>.pdf` then I have it in my documents directory, too. But as Martin already pointed out, deleting the auxiliary files makes only sense when you are really sure that your pdf file is finished.

If you want to copy the created pdf then use

```
\usepackage{shellesc}
\AtEndDocument{\ShellEscape{cp /<target>/\jobname.pdf /home/voss/}}
```

replace `/home/voss/` with the directory where the pdf should be copied to. 
Then run the document with

```
pdflatex --shell-escape -output-directory=<target> <file>
```

However, writing a small script seems to be easier.

Comment: Does anybody know how to get this to work with Kile (in combination with Okular but even just Kile would be a start)? I can get pdflatex to put the files in another directory but then Kile can't find them. I tried setting the relative directory in the build settings but all that seemed to do was screw up my ability to change settings and delete a bunch of custom keyboard short-cuts which wasn't quite the effect I had hoped for. Unfortunately, the help only explains obvious things.

Comment: This is great, but not very compatible with bibtex calls that lack the option. Is there a workaround for that ? [The accepted solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12686) is slightly horrendous.

Comment: you can run `bibtex` in that `output-directory` with `bibtes file.aux` Then it creates the `bbl`-file which should then be read by the main document.

Comment: Any way to get the tex and pdf saved on your working folder but the the auxilary files written on the temporary folder?

Comment: Write into the preamble: `\AtEndDocument{\ShellEscape{cp /tmp/\jobname.pdf /home/<user>}}` my target dir was `/tmp`. You have to run the document with `pdflatex -output-directory=<target> --shell-escape <file>` which needs package `shellesc`. However, writing a short script seems to be easier ...

Comment: Now it is 2021. When people mention Herbert's answer, they mean this one.

Answer (score 34):

No, TeX itself can't delete files, just create or overwrite them. You need to use an external tool, like a LaTeX editor or Makefile to delete it for you. For example `latexmk` has a `-c` option which cleans up all auxiliary files.

I also use Makefiles under Linux which contain a `clean` rule which remove all auxiliary files. However, this isn't really a good way under Windows. At least if you are not used to it. You can find a list of auxiliary file extension in the thread [Which auxiliary LaTeX files should be ignored by Version Control Software?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/which-auxiliary-latex-files-should-be-ignored-by-version-control-software)).

However, you should note that removing auxiliary files often will have an negative impact on compile time. You will then be forced to compile your document 2-3 times or sometimes more often. Some (La)TeX compilers (e.g. MikTeX) also offer to place the auxiliary files in a different folder. This way they don't annoy you in your main folder.

Comment: I'm using `latexmk` and it is helpful also for cleaning purposes. LaTeX can be very creative in terms of auxiliary/temp files. To that end, you might want to edit `~/.latexmk` and add something like `$clean_ext = "synctex.gz pdfsync out bbl %R.%R.table %R.%R.gnuplot";`, depending on your needs which are derived from the packages you're using.

Comment: One can find such a list from numerous `.gitignore` templates found on the Web. E.g. https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/tex

Answer (score 22):

Unfortunately, `latexmk -c` does not delete all generated files by default. For example, it does not delete files generated for glossary, acronym and index creation.

I managed to have `latexmk -c` delete more temporary files by creating a global `.latexmkrc` file (on Unix-like systems, put it into your home directory):

```perl
@generated_exts = qw(aux idx ind lof lot out toc acn acr alg glg glo gls ist);
```

In general, though, I prefer using the solution of Herbert, the `-output-directory` flag for latex, which is also supported by latexmk.

Comment: Not to forget the extra ton of auxilary files generated by synctex, beamer, biblatex and further packages (.synctex.gz .nav .vrb .snm .blg -blx.bib .bbl, .run.xml) to mention a few. The list is endless; Herberts approach really is the way to go!

Comment: For more information on where to put the `.latexmkrc` file, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41149/4012 or p. 9f of the [latexmk documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/latexmk).

Comment: what about the `$cleanup_includes_cusdep_generated` and `$cleanup_includes_generated` flags of `latexmk` ? These should take care of such cases (haven't tried it)

Answer (score 22):

Another solution is to use the `--clean` flag from `rubber`.

[`rubber`](https://launchpad.net/rubber) is, according to the project description, "a program whose purpose is to handle all tasks related to the compilation of LaTeX documents. This includes compiling the document itself, of course, enough times so that all references are defined, and running BibTeX to manage bibliographic references. Automatic execution of dvips to produce PostScript documents is also included, as well as usage of pdfLaTeX to produce PDF documents."

Let's say I have a `mydoc.tex` file which creates the following auxiliary files:

```
mydoc.aux   mydoc.ilg   mydoc.log
mydoc.idx   mydoc.ind   mydoc.toc
```

besides of course of `mydoc.pdf`. When running the following command

```
rubber --clean mydoc
```

only two files remain:

```
mydoc.pdf mydoc.tex
```

If I want to have only `mydoc.tex`, using `rubber --pdf --clean mydoc` will do the job.

According to the manual:

- `--clean`: Remove all files produced by the compilation, instead of building the document. This option is present in rubber only. It applies to the compilation as it would be done with the other options of the command line, i.e. saying `rubber --clean foo` will not delete `foo.ps`, while saying `rubber --ps --clean foo` will.

In case you need some "advanced" cleanup process, there's also a `clean` directive. A directive is a line like

```
% rubber: cmd args
```

The line must begin with a `%`, then any sequence of `%` signs and spaces, then the text `rubber:` followed by zero or more spaces and a directive name, possibly followed by spaces and arguments.

Lets say we have a `dummy.txt` file generated on every compilation of `mydoc.tex`. I want to get rid of it, so I add the following directive in `mydoc.tex`:

```
% rubber: clean dummy.txt
\documentclass{article}
...
```

Now, when running `rubber --clean mydoc`, `dummy.txt` will be removed. According to the manual:

- `clean <file>` Indicates that the specified file should be removed when cleaning using `--clean`.

There we go, a clean project folder. `:)`

Answer (score 18):

There is @paulo's awesome [`arara`](http://cereda.github.io/arara/) (*The cool TeX automation tool*) without which I can't imagine working anymore. It has a predefined `clean` directive that allows to specify which files should be seleted after compilation.  The following file called `test.tex` would be compiled twice and then the `aux` and the `toc` file would be removed:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: clean: { files: [ test.aux , test.toc ] }
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Test}

foo

\end{document}
```

As I found it tedious to specify the whole filename that should be removed (I had to prepare about 60 different small files where I wanted the directory cleaned up after successfull compilation) [I asked @paulo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=12167057#12167057) if there was an `arara` equivalent for `\jobname`

```
% arara: clean: { files: [ \jobname.aux, \jobname.log ] }
```

that would allow me simply copying the `arara` directives from one file to the next. [He came up](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12167091#12167091) with the following nice rule (thanks again @paulo):

```
!config
identifier: remove
name: Remove
command: <arara> @{remove}
arguments:
- identifier: remove
  default: <arara> @{isNotEmpty(item, isWindows("cmd /c del", "rm -f").concat(' "').concat(getBasename(file))concat('.').concat(item).concat('"'))}
```

With this rule correctly installed the above example becomes

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: remove: { items: [ aux , toc ] }
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Test}

foo

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there is particular reason, why `remove` is not included in the 3.0 version? I find it quite useful and I would imagine many people would use it.

Comment: You need to ask Paulo but IIRC this rule was created later than v3.0

Comment: @clemens I am sorry, but this approach fails when trying to remove files of extensions like `run.xml` or `synctex.gz`. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou ask Paulo. This rule was written by him…

Comment: This does not work for me: Windows 11 lualatex. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 14):

In case you are using **Emacs** with **AucTeX**, just run

```
M-x TeX-clean
```

This does not get rid of any temporary directories that are created, just files

Answer (score 8):

A variant of Herbert's answer:

In MiKTeX, you can specify an `aux-directory`, where all the auxiliary files (ergo basically everything except the pdf) are written, so use e.g.

```
pdflatex foo.tex --aux-directory="C:\Users\JaneDoe\Documents\LaTeX\auxiliaries-global"
```

As a result you'll get foo.pdf in whatever directory foo.tex is; foo.aux, foo.out and whatnot go in the `aux-directory` that you specified.

As has been noted, it's not recommended to delete the auxiliary files every time, but this is a neat way of "hiding" them and keeping your working directories from getting cluttered.

Since I don't use TeX Live (yet), I don't know if there's a comparable tweak for it.

Comment: Isn't it dangerous to use one global directory because there might exist `foo.tex` in two directories that end up overwriting their auxiliary files in the global directory?

Comment: @Christian: You pinpointed a possible disadvantage of this method. However, I've been using it for some time and have never run into trouble. After all, I suppose LaTeX will just overwrite the old auxiliary files and perhaps be slightly confused on the first run?

Comment: For others who want to use this solution: Bibtex may not be too happy with this solution. Bibtex needs the aux file, but it also needs the bib file, which is (typically) not stored in the global aux folder. I fixed this by making bibtex search in a different folder (the same folder as the tex file -- that's where I store my bib file) for the bib file.

Comment: Winedt users can do this very easily as shown in this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87818/11232. This way The disadvantage raised by @Christian Lindig can be over come.

Comment: This works great for .aux, .log, .toc, etc, but it still puts the .synctex file in the same folder as the .tex and .pdf files. Do you know how to make it put the .synctex file in a temporary folder as well?

Comment: @DonaldDuck I don't think this is (easily) possible. When you're viewing the pdf with a synctex-compatible pdf viewer (e.g. SumatraPDF) and double-click a word in the pdf, the viewer will open your editor at the corresponding code line, which it looks up in the .synctex file. So we'd need configuration for the viewer telling it where to look for the .synctex file. I haven't seen anything like that yet. If, however, you're not using the synctex functionality, you can turn it off when compiling so the .synctex file won't be produced at all.

Answer (score 8):

For manual deletion, the latex editor [TeXstudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/) (and probably its parent [TeXmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) as well) contains an option "Clean Auxiliary Files" in the Tools menu.

As advised in other answers, aux file deletion should only be done manually when document no longer needs any further editing.

Comment: TeXstudio "Clean Auxiliary Files" does not delete .bcf, .run.xml, and .synctex.gz

Comment: Its easy to write all these extensions in the respective dialog box.

Comment: Just an update: in TexStudio 2.12.6, *Clean auxiliary files...* is no longer in the Edit menu, but in the Tools menu.

Comment: You can specify the extensions to be cleaned in **Tools -> Clean Auxiliary Files**. And you can set a shortcut in **Preferences -> Shortcuts -> Tools -> Clean Auxiliary Files**.

Answer (score 7):

FWIW, in ConTeXT you can delete the temporary files by passing `--purge` to the command line program `context`. Thus

```
  context --purge filename
```

will run context multiple times and then delete the auxiliary and log files.

Answer (score 4):

**A TeXShop solution (Mac OS)**

As others have mentioned, deleting auxiliary files as a matter of course is not usually a good idea, especially for complex documents.  However, it is useful to be able to delete them manually when needed.

I use the following Applescript (written by Claus Gerhardt) saved as a macro in TeXShop. The script could also be adapted to other Mac editors.  What I like about this script is that I can add new aux file extensions when needed, and it is able to deal with multiple part aux extensions such as `-blx.bib`, etc.

```
--AppleScript
-- Apply only to an already saved file
-- Claus Gerhardt, September 2006
(*This script gets the path of the frontmost (tex) document in TeXShop and removes the corresponding auxilary files the suffixes of which are listed in the list L. Beware of the quotation marks. The list L may contain suffixes to which no corresponding files exist.*)

my remove_auxiliaries()
on remove_auxiliaries()
    set L to {".aux", ".synctex.gz", ".fdb_latexmk", ".out", ".toc", ".bbl", ".blg", ".ind", ".sind", ".run.xml","-blx.bib",".log", ".end", ".1"} as list

    tell application "TeXShop"
        get path of document of window 1
        set fileName to result
    end tell

    set {baseName, texName, pdfName, namePath, dirName, dirNameunquoted, logName, logPath, rtfName, docName} to my setnamebbedit_rootn(fileName)


(*
tell application "TeXShop"
    close document docName
end tell
*)

    repeat with x in L
        try
            set shellScript to "cd " & dirName & ";"
            set shellScript to shellScript & "rm -f  " & baseName &  x
            do shell script shellScript
        end try
    end repeat

end remove_auxiliaries

on setnamebbedit_rootn(x)
    set n to (number of characters of contents of x)
    set fileNamequoted to quoted form of x
    set windowName to do shell script "basename " & fileNamequoted
    set m to (number of characters of contents of windowName)
    set dirName to quoted form of (characters 1 thru (n - m - 1) of x as string)
    set dirNameunquoted to (characters 1 thru (n - m - 1) of x as string)
    set theText to contents of windowName as string

    set n to (number of characters of contents of theText)
    set i to n as number

    repeat while i > 0
        if character i of theText is equal to "." then
            set m to i
            exit repeat
        else
            set i to (i - 1)
        end if
    end repeat

    set baseName to (characters 1 thru (m - 1) of theText as string)
    set texName to baseName & ".tex"
    set namePath to dirNameunquoted & "/" & baseName as string
    set pdfName to namePath & ".pdf" as string
    set rtfName to namePath & ".rtf" as string
    set logPath to namePath & ".log" as string
    set logName to baseName & ".log" as string

    set theFile to POSIX file x as string
    tell application "Finder"
        get displayed name of the file theFile
    end tell
    set docName to result


    return {baseName, texName, pdfName, namePath, dirName, dirNameunquoted, logName, logPath, rtfName, docName} as list
end setnamebbedit_rootn
```

Comment: Why I use it, it reported in TexShop: Excepted expression but found end of line. What's the matter?

Comment: @WonderTree No idea. What version of the Mac OS and TeXShop are you using?

Comment: Moutain Lion and the version of texshop is 3.11. I just copied the code in macro in Texshop, should i need do another thing?

Comment: Update: this script still seems to work for me on Mavericks.

Answer (score 3):

There is a (slightly hacky) solution which uses `latexmk` only to clean up:

```
pdflatex <file>
latexmk -c
```

Answer (score 3):

For TexMaker, a convenient option is to check *Launch the "Clean" tool when exiting TeXmaker*:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also do Windows shell scripting with LaTeX as follows.

### Main input file

Let `main.tex` be your main input file that you want to compile and delete its auxiliary files.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=2cm,landscape]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\label{eq:Einstein}
\end{equation}
\newpage
See equation~\ref{eq:Einstein} on page~\pageref{eq:Einstein}.
\end{document}
```

### Shell scripting input file

Create additional input file for shell scripting as follows.

```
% host.tex
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgffor,graphicx}

\foreach \x in {1,...,3}{\immediate\write18{latex main && dvips -t unknown main && ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None main.ps}}

\foreach \ext in {aux,log,dvi,ps}{\immediate\write18{cmd /c del main.\ext}}

\begin{document}
\pdfximage{main.pdf}
\foreach \ip in {1,...,\the\pdflastximagepages}{\fbox{\includegraphics[page=\ip,scale=0.5]{main}}\endgraf}
\end{document}
```

The code snippet below

```
\foreach \ext in {aux,log,dvi,ps}{\immediate\write18{cmd /c del main.\ext}}
```

removes the auxiliary files.

### Compile with `pdflatex -shell-escape`

Compile the `host.tex` with `pdflatex -shell-escape host`. And you will get an output as follows to make sure everything was done properly.

[image]

### Complete code

The following code simulates everything in one invocation of  `pdflatex`. Make sure to compile it with `pdflatex -shell-escape host`.

```
% host.tex
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{main.tex}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=2cm,landscape]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\label{eq:Einstein}
\end{equation}
\newpage
See equation~\ref{eq:Einstein} on page~\pageref{eq:Einstein}.
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pgffor,graphicx}

\foreach \x in {1,...,3}{\immediate\write18{latex main && dvips -t unknown main && ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None main.ps}}

\foreach \ext in {aux,log,dvi,ps}{\immediate\write18{cmd /c del main.\ext}}

\begin{document}
\pdfximage{main.pdf}
\foreach \ip in {1,...,\the\pdflastximagepages}{\fbox{\includegraphics[page=\ip,scale=0.5]{main}}\endgraf}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm on linux and I have written the following bash script that is always running:

```
#!/bin/bash

inotifywait -m -r ~/Documents -e create |
    while read path action file; do
      echo "$file $path $action";
      if [[ "$file" =~ .*\.(aux|log) ]]
        then
        if [[ ! -f "$path"/.hidden ]] || ! (grep -Fxq "$file" "$path"/.hidden)
           then
           echo "hide file"
           echo "$file" >> "$path"/.hidden
        fi
      fi
    done
```

What this does:
It first looks in the home folder with the documents if any documents get created. If the created document is an aux or a log, it add the file to a special hidden file so that the file explorer (nemo in my case) knows it should not show the file.

The advantage is that for latex everything works as it should. Not all file explorers support this, but when it does, this is a nice solution.

You can modify this for your own use.

Answer (score 0):

### Cleaning whole directories / Windows only solution

I'm drafting documents for a certain project in a project directory. Different documents, different version, no versioning system like e.g. git. After a while the project ends and I'll never again compile exactly these *.tex files in this directory.

At this time, I'll copy a powershell file into the project directory, called "Putzdienst.ps1" = cleaningservice.ps1.

It removes all the files I no longer need. Works only on Windows, but of course a Linux or Mac OS X solution wouldn't be much longer. You can simply add all the file types you'd like to delete. Beware, these files will just be *deleted* ! No backup, no waste paper basket -- GONE!

This is the code of "Putzdienst.ps1", adapt to your needs:

```
    function Get-ScriptDirectory{
    $Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value
    Split-Path $Invocation.MyCommand.Path
}

$path = (Get-ScriptDirectory)

cd $path


remove-item  *.log |% {remove-item $_}

get-childitem *.toc |% {remove-item $_}

get-childitem *.gz |% {remove-item $_}

get-childitem *.aux |% {remove-item $_}

get-childitem *.nav |% {remove-item $_}

get-childitem *.out |% {remove-item $_}

get-childitem *.synctex |% {remove-item $_}

get-childitem *.synctex.gz |% {remove-item $_}

get-childitem *.tmp |% {remove-item $_}

get-childitem *.4ct |% {remove-item $_}

get-childitem *.4tc |% {remove-item $_}

get-childitem *.anl |% {remove-item $_}

get-childitem *.lg |% {remove-item $_}

get-childitem *.idv |% {remove-item $_}

get-childitem *.xref |% {remove-item $_}
```

Comment: "a Linux or Mac OS X solution wouldn't be much longer" you mean much shorter :P

Answer (score 0):

## MiKTeX based solution

MiKTeX users can look into the `--clean` or `-c` option available with their `texify` command. [Reference](https://docs.miktex.org/manual/texify.html)