# How to prevent TeXShop from making .aux, .syntec.gz and .log while compiling?

Tags: compiling, auxiliary-files, texshop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent pdflatex from writing a bunch of files.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11123/prevent-pdflatex-from-writing-a-bunch-of-files)

I'm not a super-user of LaTeX, I only use it for small reports with lots of maths. I often have to do it with other people so we put everything in a dropbox folder. Is there a way to prevent TexShop from making all those .aux, .syntec.gz and .log files while compiling ? We don't use them at all and it makes our folder pretty messy when we have several documents in LaTeX.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [Prevent pdflatex from writing a bunch of files.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11123/prevent-pdflatex-from-writing-a-bunch-of-files). Have a look on it and tell use if you still have questions. Note these files are used by the compiler itself and are always created, except if you use `\nofiles` in the preamble. However, you won't get any table of contents or any cross-referencing! See also [Deleting external/auxiliary files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24785/deleting-external-auxiliary-files).

Comment: TeXShop-specific: In your ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines folder, copy XeLaTeX.engine to a file PdfLaTeXhide.engine.  Modify the `xelatex` command to begin with `pdflatex`; then append a line `SetFile -a V *.aux *.log *.synctex.gz`.  This will hide all the aux files in the Finder. To use it, select "PdfLaTeXhide" in the typeset menu of your TeXShop window (after restarting TeXShop.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. LaTeX creates and uses these and some other files. You can look at them and you will understand its use. For example, `*.aux` files are used to include labels positions which will be read in a second compilation, `*.toc` contains table of contents, `*.bbl` bibliography information, etc.

You cannot avoid them but use [Leo Liu's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32435/how-to-prevent-texshop-from-making-aux-syntec-gz-and-log-while-compiling/32437#32437) solution to place them in another folder.

Answer (score 8):

Configure your TeXShop to use

```
pdflatex -output-directory=SOME_OTHER_DIR
```

command.

Comment: This will break the feature that the pdf is shown after typesetting. See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67211/use-texshop-preview-window-when-different-output-dir-is-set).