# Problems with biblatex authoryear style

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am writing my Bachelor Thesis and am facing some problems with the `biblatex` package.

I have the following line in my text:

```
\citet{Lerner.2002} look at this issue [...]
```

I want this to show like this:

> Lerner and Tirole (2002) look at this issue [...]

However, when I use

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,natbib=true,sortcites=true,block=space]{biblatex}
```

(which I think is the right option?) I get the title:

> Lerner and Tirole ("Some simple economics of open source") look at this issue [...]

I am really confused about this, can anybody help?
I am using Texmaker and MiKTeX 2.9, if that makes any difference.

EDIT: The .bib entry looks like this:

```
 @article{Lerner.2002,
 author = {Lerner, Josh and Tirole, Jean},
 year = {2002},
 title = {Some Simple Economics of Open Source},
 pages = {197--234},
 volume = {50},
 number = {2},
 issn = {00221821},
 journal = {The Journal of Industrial Economics}
}
```

Comment: What does the `.bib` entry look like? We can't reproduce your problem without more information…

Comment: I tried to test this, and for me it also used the title, without a year. If I change to natbib it does function. Btw my bibtex is created by mendeley.

Comment: Hello Seamus, the .bib entry looks like this:
@article{Lerner.2002,
 author = {Lerner, Josh and Tirole, Jean},
 year = {2002},
 title = {Some Simple Economics of Open Source},
 pages = {197--234},
 volume = {50},
 number = {2},
 issn = {00221821},
 journal = {The Journal of Industrial Economics}
}

Comment: I solved the problem somehow, but cannot reproduce how exactly unforunately. I tried switching to natbib, didn't find what I wanted there, and when I switched back to BibLatex, somehow it started working like a charm. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad your problem was solved. It might've been the auxiliary files, which got rewritten when you used `natbib`. When you're facing strange problems with your bibliography (or table of contents, ...), it's always a good idea to [delete your auxiliary files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24785/4012) (e.g. via `latexmk -c`) and compile again. We'll probably close this question as _too localized_ because the problem isn't really reproducible, but don't take offense from that, it's just part of our keeping tidy here. Looking forward to more posts of yours on tex.sx!

Answer (score 1):

A MWE using all the information you supplied does produce the desired output on my machine, using Texmaker and MiKTeX 2.9.
Is there anything else in your preamble related to bibliographies?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Lerner.2002, 
    author = {Lerner, Josh and Tirole, Jean}, 
    year = {2002}, 
    title = {Some Simple Economics of Open Source}, 
    pages = {197--234}, 
    volume = {50}, 
    number = {2}, 
    issn = {00221821}, 
    journal = {The Journal of Industrial Economics} 
} 
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    natbib=true,
    sortcites=true,
    block=space
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 

\begin{document}
\citet{Lerner.2002} look at this issue [...]
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed to natbib, since Rick de Gout suggested it, and did not get the desired result there.
Then I switched back to BibLatex, and somehow it worked. Maybe I just had to rebuild BibTex, though I am sure that I had done that before I asked this question. So it works now, but thank you!

Comment: You should not use the `natbib` and `biblatex` packages at the same time, they are doing similar things, but they are not compatible. But `biblatex` has an option `natbib` and if you set it to `true` (as in the MWE), you can use the `\citet{}` and `\citep{}` commands.