# disable lyx cache for compiling

Tags: lyx, glossaries

When compiling the document for the first time after opening LyX, it requires some time.

For another run, it is finished almost immediately. LyX seems to use a cache, if it thinks that there are no changes.

I need to disable that cache, because I manually run makeglossaries in the working directory of LyX and LyX does not recognize that.

Any idea?

Comment: Related, I think: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65411/how-can-i-force-lyx-to-rebuild-intermediate-files-for-clean-pdf-display