# latex gives me the error: Ouch---my internal constants have been clobbered

Tags: texlive, texmf

As the title states, compiling with latex produces the error, right away:

```
Ouch---my internal constants have been clobbered!---case 14
```

I have no idea what this means... I use TexLive 2012. I updated my texmf.cnf and ran fmtutil-sys and texhash. I guess texhash may have messed it up?

Any ideas?

As requested a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    Any tex file.
\end{document}
```

Comment: latex will not even start compiling. That's the problem. It doesn't matter what tex file...

Comment: Delete all auxiliary files created from the previous run. See [File extensions of LaTeX-related files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7770/5764) or [Deleting external/auxiliary files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24785/5764) for some ideas. Then try to rerun your example code.

Comment: what did you do with your `texmf.cnf`? In general there is no need to modify that file. At least use a local one.

Comment: I require quite a bit more memory for my compilations as I have large plots, animations and interactive components. These are very heavy during compilation.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The error message

```
Ouch---my internal constants have been clobbered!---case 14
```

is caused by

```
if (mem_min<min_halfword)or(mem_max>=max_halfword)or@|
  (mem_bot-mem_min>max_halfword+1) then bad:=14;
```

in `pdftex.web`. Probably you have changed the memory settings in texmf.cnf that triggers the error. For further analysis these changes would be useful.

### Maximal `main_memory`

`tex.ch` changes the code lines above to:

```
if (mem_bot-sup_main_memory<min_halfword)or@|
  (mem_top+sup_main_memory>=max_halfword) then bad:=14;
```

Also it defines `max_halfword` as:

```
@d max_halfword==@"FFFFFFF {largest allowable value in a |halfword|}
```

That is 2<sup>28</sup>-1 = 268,435,455. The value for `sup_main_memory`:

```
@!sup_main_memory = 256000000;
```

And `mem_top` is initialized as:

```
mem_top := mem_bot + main_memory -1;
```

Then the latest condition for triggering the error becomes:

`mem_top` + `sup_mem_memory` ≥ `max_half_word`
  `main_memory` ≥ `max_halfword` - `sup_main_memory` + 1
  `main_memory` ≥ 12,435,456

or `main_memory` must be smaller or equal than **12,435,455**.

### Memory units

From `tex.web`:

```
@!mem : array[mem_min..mem_max] of memory_word; {the big dynamic storage area}
...
@!memory_word = record@;@/
  case four_choices of
  1: (@!int:integer);
  2: (@!gr:glue_ratio);
  3: (@!hh:two_halves);
  4: (@!qqqq:four_quarters);
  end;
```

The translation to bytes seems to be system dependent, from `texmfmem.h` my guess for `memory_word` are four or eight bytes.

Comment: Indeed, I apparently had one too many zeros for the `main_memory` entry. Reread the config files. No more error! Thank you!

Comment: Is there an easy way to find out the `max_halfword`? In the TeX sources I found a `#define` that set it to 1073741823 but this error occurs way before my `main_memory` variable reaches that value.

Comment: @Christian I have updated the answer to add some calculation for `main_memory`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Oh that's great. This works indeed just so :) Just out of curiosity, are these bytes, words or what else? If it's bytes, that's awfully few :/

Comment: @Christian Answer updated with my guesses for the size of the memory units.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thanks again! I was silently hoping for 4K blocks or something but well, I guess TeX's age just shows in such things.

Comment: Message from ten years later: here I am fighting the same error. Maybe it's time TeX updated its handling of memory?

Anyway, thanks @HeikoOberdiek, you're the GOAT.

Comment: This a cursed way to handle being out of memory in 2023.