# Why does LaTeX impose a memory limit of 8,000,000 and can I circumvent it?

Tags: pgfplots, tex-core, memory

A few people have already asked the question of how to increase the maximum memory LaTeX is allowed to use (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7953/how-to-expand-texs-main-memory-size-pgfplots-memory-overload) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75399/increasing-texs-main-memory)) because it is quite common for LaTeX to run out of memory when using, for example, `pgfplots` to plot experimental data.

Following the instructions from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7954/32206), I managed to successfully increase the memory limit. However, I was not able to increase the limit to an amount capable of processing a 10,000-data-points plot. When I ran `fmtutil-sys --all` as instructed, the process terminated with errors. The problem was that, according to `texmf.cnf`, I had exceeded the memory limit by using `main_memory = 50000000`:

`% Memory. Must be less than 8,000,000 total.`

I was wondering why that is the case and whether there is a way to circumvent that limit. If there isn't a limit, what are the maximum values I can set the `main_memory`, `extra_mem_top` and `extra_mem_bot` to? Do the latter two count towards the total memory (I assume they do!)? Is there another variable that is more closely related to the "type of memory" that `pgfplots` uses so that I can increase that instead?

For your information, I externalize my figures using `mode=list and make` and I already tried `lualatex`, but I'm it still complains about running out of memory (even though it uses only around 1Gb of RAM).

I understand that people will argue that it is unnecessary to plot such a large number of data points in such a short space, but I would at least to know why LaTeX imposes such memory limits, especially with memory being so cheap these days.

Comment: 'Classical' TeX uses fixed size arrays: it's not computer RAM that limits things. I'm no Pascal/C programmer, but my guess is that either hard-coded in the sources or within the compile chain there is a difficult-to-remove limit. Note that LuaTeX uses dynamic allocation, so this does not (usually) occur, and that this is not LaTeX's fault as it's at the engine level. There are also several different arrays to worry about!

Comment: @JosephWright: Interesting. I wasn't aware that TeX used fixed-size arrays. If `LuaLaTeX` uses dynamic memory allocation, why do I still get an out of memory error when I use it? Its would simplify things immensely, but I can't seem to make it allocate memory dynamically as advertised.

Comment: I use LuaTeX for some files with 32k points, which don't plot with pdfTeX. In that case there is no need to fiddle with anything other than choice of engine. I think an example might be useful.

Comment: While `main_memory` can be 8000000 at most, you can use `extra_mem_top` and `extra_mem_bot`

Comment: @JosephWright: I think I figured out why `LuaLaTeX` wasn't working properly for me. It's because I wasn't really using it! The `makefile` produced by `mode=list and make` uses `pdflatex` even though I'm generating the document with `lualatex`. I changed `pgfplots`'s `system call` to `lualatex` which fixed the `makefile`, and I am now waiting to see whether the figure is produced. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @egreg: That's great. Thanks. Is there a limit to what those two values can be?

Comment: @sudosensei I don't really know. Do your own experiments.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks a lot for that link. If either of you would be so kind as to provide a short answer (a combination of Joseph's and your first comment?), I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: @sudosensei I believe that it's better to mark this as duplicate