# Plot every nth point except for a region in the middle

Tags: pgfplots

I found these neat little additions [here](http://latexbucket.blogspot.com/2011/07/extension-of-each-nth-point-for.html), but I'm having a hard time reading the code:

```
\makeatletter
\def\pgfplotsutil@decstringcounter#1{%
    \begingroup
        \c@pgf@counta=#1\relax
        \advance\c@pgf@counta by -1
        \edef#1{\the\c@pgf@counta}%
        \pgfmath@smuggleone#1%
    \endgroup
}%

\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/each nth point**/.style 2 args={%
        /pgfplots/x filter/.append code={%
            \ifnum\coordindex=0
                \def\c@pgfplots@eachnthpoint@xfilter{#2}%
                \def\c@pgfplots@eachnthpoint@xfilter@zero{0}%
            \fi
            \ifx\c@pgfplots@eachnthpoint@xfilter@zero\c@pgfplots@eachnthpoint@xfilter
                \def\c@pgfplots@eachnthpoint@xfilter{#1}%
            \else
                \let\pgfmathresult\pgfutil@empty
            \fi
            \pgfplotsutil@decstringcounter\c@pgfplots@eachnthpoint@xfilter
        }%
    },
}

\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/each nth point*/.style 2 args={%
        /pgfplots/x filter/.append code={%
            \ifnum\coordindex=0
                \def\c@pgfplots@eachnthpoint@xfilter{0}%
                \edef\c@pgfplots@eachnthpoint@xfilter@cmp{#1}%
            \else
                \ifnum\coordindex>#2\relax
                    \pgfplotsutil@advancestringcounter\c@pgfplots@eachnthpoint@xfilter
                    \ifx\c@pgfplots@eachnthpoint@xfilter@cmp\c@pgfplots@eachnthpoint@xfilter
                        \def\c@pgfplots@eachnthpoint@xfilter{0}%
                    \else
                        \let\pgfmathresult\pgfutil@empty
                    \fi
                \fi
            \fi
        }%
    },
}
\makeatother
```

I'm familiar with the use of `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` and I'm familiar with programming concepts, but this syntax always gives me trouble.

1. Does `each nth point**` shift the plotted points vertically?
2. I know in general that `each nth point*` plots every point at the beginning, then starts plotting every nth point after a specified number of data points.

   a. Does the first `if` plot the first coordinate and then redefine a variable for the remainder of the data points?  Using the first argument?

   b. Does the first `if` inside the first `else` activate when the data point corresponding to the second argument is reached?

   c. Is the rest of the code just from the normal `each nth point` code, with the nested `else` throwing out/not plotting the point for any index that gets there?

There is a point (no pun intended) to this exercise.  I'd like to alter `every nth point*` so that it will take 3 arguments instead of two (I presume `/.style 2 args=` becomes `/.style 3 args=`) so it can plot every nth point except for a certain region (arg2 < x < arg3) in which every point will be plotted.

Comment: For the final part, there's no `/.style 3 args=` for more than two arguments there's `/.style n args=`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina oh okay, how do i specify that i'd like 3 arguments instead of more?

Comment: You use `/.style n args={3}{code with #1 #2 #3}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've added some comments for the code given. The first part is an overkill for my taste though. It is just a function to decrease a counter value and the argument is a number. Same can be easily done by other means but anyways.

```
\makeatletter
\def\pgfplotsutil@decstringcounter#1{%
    \begingroup% Standard scoping for the actions
        \c@pgf@counta=#1\relax% Equate the temp TikZ counter to #1
        \advance\c@pgf@counta by -1% Decrease the temp TikZ counter by 1
        \edef#1{\the\c@pgf@counta}%Redefine the argument #1
        \pgfmath@smuggleone#1% Make sure the argument has this meaning after the scope ends.
    \endgroup% End scoping
}%
```

Then we have a slightly more involved one

```
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/each nth point**/.style 2 args={%A style def that takes 2 arguments
        /pgfplots/x filter/.append code={%Add the following code to the existing key code
            \ifnum\coordindex=0% Obvious! 
% If true define the following two counters as such (but they are not actual TeX counters!)
                \def\c@pgfplots@eachnthpoint@xfilter{#2}%
                \def\c@pgfplots@eachnthpoint@xfilter@zero{0}%
            \fi% End of if
% Here it is again a bit I-wouldn't-do-that code. Compares the values of two "counters".
% What is implemented here is simply taking a Mod(myvalue,n) is zero? op. 
% If yes then Reset the "counter" to n and don't touch \pgfmathresult (point is passed)
% If no empty \pgfmathresult so (point is discarded)
            \ifx\c@pgfplots@eachnthpoint@xfilter@zero\c@pgfplots@eachnthpoint@xfilter
                \def\c@pgfplots@eachnthpoint@xfilter{#1}%
            \else
                \let\pgfmathresult\pgfutil@empty
            \fi
% Decrease the coord count by 1 and done. Hence next the  "obvious" \ifnum is skipped
            \pgfplotsutil@decstringcounter\c@pgfplots@eachnthpoint@xfilter
        }%
    },
}
```

Now to the single starred version (I skipped the similar parts)

```
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/each nth point*/.style 2 args={%
        /pgfplots/x filter/.append code={% Same
            \ifnum\coordindex=0% Same 
                \def\c@pgfplots@eachnthpoint@xfilter{0}% Same
                \edef\c@pgfplots@eachnthpoint@xfilter@cmp{#1}% Same
            \else% Same 
                \ifnum\coordindex>#2\relax% If we passed a certain coordinate num
% We don't have the def on the next macro but naming is obvious
% It is very similar to the above but this time the counter is increased from 0 to n
                    \pgfplotsutil@advancestringcounter\c@pgfplots@eachnthpoint@xfilter
% If the comparator value and the actual counter is equal?
                    \ifx\c@pgfplots@eachnthpoint@xfilter@cmp\c@pgfplots@eachnthpoint@xfilter%
% Yes reset the counter and don't touch \pgfmathresult (point is passed)
                        \def\c@pgfplots@eachnthpoint@xfilter{0}%
                    \else    
% No empty and point is discarded
                        \let\pgfmathresult\pgfutil@empty
                    \fi% 
                \fi%
            \fi%
        }%
    },
}
\makeatother
```

I think this is a very convoluted way of doing things. Following does the same, with three arguments as you asked for. You can remove the comments to go back to the compact version.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
my filter/.style args={every#1between#2and#3}{%
/pgfplots/x filter/.append code={%
\ifnum\coordindex<#2%
  % Nothing
\else% Did we pass #3?
  \ifnum\coordindex>#3%
    %Nothing
  \else% Ok filter is on, don't disturb \pgfmathresult for convenience
    \pgfmathsetmacro\temp{int(mod(\coordindex,#1))}%
    \ifnum0=\temp\relax% Are we on the nth point?
      % Yes do nothing let it pass
    \else% discard it
      \let\pgfmathresult\pgfutil@empty
    \fi%
  \fi%
\fi%
}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my filter=every 50 between 700 and 1000]
% If works properly we should see some ragged part among the smooth part
\addplot[samples=1501] {sin(deg(5*x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this looks awesome, let me try to see if i can figure it out.  i actually need the opposite, what i meant by 'so it can plot every nth point except for a certain region (arg2 < x < arg3) in which every point will be plotted' was ragged everywhere except a smooth part in the middle

Comment: i'll accept this one, i just ended up asking this as a follow up question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232437/style-args-syntax-for-negative-not-except-to-make-this-cleaner-code)

Comment: This is awesome! (Getting close to the ideal: a "dynamic" each nth point option!)

Comment: @Bibi You can use the same key more than once ;)

Comment: Hmm... This is AWESOME! ;)