# drawing an orthonormal frame with semi circles

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, framed, tikz-styles

[image]

Hi, I have a problem in drawing this frame, and with colors, especially using tikz programs or the hobby the program don't compile with hobby. Can anyone help me in drawing this pic?

thank you.

i was using these codes:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby,patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,->] (52,0) -- (60,0) node[anchor=north west] {$x'$};
\draw[thick,->] (56,-04) -- (56,04) node[anchor=south east] {$x_N$};
\node[draw=red,dashed,thick,circle,minimum width=4cm] (n) at (56,0) {};
\fill[pattern=north east lines,opacity=.6] (58,0)arc(0:180:2cm) -- (58,0);
\draw[thick,->] (57.5,1.55) -- (58,2) node[anchor=north west] {$I^{+}(1)$};
\draw[thick,->] (57.5,-1.55) -- (58,-2) node[anchor=north west] {$I(1)$};
\draw (56,0) node[below right] {$O$} node{$\bullet$};
\draw (58,0) node[below right] {$1$} node{};
\draw (54,0) node[below left] {$-1$} node{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, right now this is a typical *do it for me question*. Please, at least show your efforts with a [minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html).

Comment: The point is that i dont have many ideas in working like these drawing i have a tex program which draw a frame with ome circle i try to use it but its not compiling thats why i put my question here.

Comment: Then start by posting that code. You at least need to show some effort ;-)

Comment: When you say you want to add colors to the diagram, where exactly would you like to add them?

Comment: The first semi circle with color different than the second color and the mesh in the small circle to be another color...

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Is it something like that what you want?

Comment: Yes thats it exactly, thank you very much for your work

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry to bother you but I just noticed that eventhough you have upvoted answers (which is great), you still haven't accepted answers to your questions. You can accept the answers that you consider best solved your problem by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: I accept it and now i repeat the acceptance did you get it?

Comment: Yes, and I thank you for that. However, you still haven't accepted any answers. An accepted answer has a green checkmark next to it; see, for example, this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232414/3954 and the green checkmark to the left below the vote count. Clicking that checkmarks means "to accept" an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's one option:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\tikzset{
smalldot/.style={
  circle,
  fill,
  inner sep=1.2pt
  }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\draw[->] 
  (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[->] 
  (0,-1) -- (0,5);
\begin{scope}
\clip
  (-5,0) rectangle (5,5);
\draw
  (0,0) circle [radius=3cm];
\draw
  (0,0) circle [radius=4cm];
\end{scope}
\draw
  (-1,1) circle [radius=0.65cm] node[smalldot,label={below:$x_{0}$}] {};
\begin{scope}
\clip
  (0,0) circle [radius=3cm];
\draw[pattern=north east lines]
  (45:3cm) circle [radius=0.65cm];
\end{scope}
\draw
  (45:3cm) circle [radius=0.65cm] node[smalldot,label={right:$x_{0}$}] {};
\draw
  (-1,1) -- node[above left=-2pt] {$\rho$} ++(30:0.65cm);

\foreach \Posicion\Label in 
  {(3,0)/$r$,(-3,0)/$-r$,(4,0)/$1$,(-4,0)/$-1$}
{
  \node[below] at \Posicion {\strut\Label};
}
\node[anchor=north west] at (5,0)
  {$x'\in\mathbb{R}^{N-1}$};
\node[anchor=west] at (0,5)
  {$x_{N}$};
\draw[->,help lines]
  (70:3cm) to[out=40,in=180] ++(2cm,20pt) node[right,text=black] {$I^{\ast}(r)$};
\draw[->,help lines]
  (70:4cm) to[out=40,in=180] ++(2cm,20pt) node[right,text=black] {$I^{\ast}(1)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In comments it was requested to add dome color:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\tikzset{
smalldot/.style={
  circle,
  fill,
  inner sep=1.2pt
  }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\begin{scope}
\clip
  (-5,0) rectangle (5,5);
\filldraw[fill=orange!20]
  (0,0) circle [radius=4cm];
\filldraw[fill=cyan!30]
  (0,0) circle [radius=3cm];
\end{scope}
\draw[->] 
  (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[->] 
  (0,-1) -- (0,5);
\draw
  (-1,1) circle [radius=0.65cm] node[smalldot,label={below:$x_{0}$}] {};
\begin{scope}
\clip
  (0,0) circle [radius=3cm];
\filldraw[fill=red!50]
  (45:3cm) circle [radius=0.65cm];
\end{scope}
\draw
  (45:3cm) circle [radius=0.65cm] node[smalldot,label={right:$x_{0}$}] {};
\draw
  (-1,1) -- node[above left=-2pt] {$\rho$} ++(30:0.65cm);

\foreach \Posicion\Label in 
  {(3,0)/$r$,(-3,0)/$-r$,(4,0)/$1$,(-4,0)/$-1$}
{
  \node[below] at \Posicion {\strut\Label};
}
\node[anchor=north west] at (5,0)
  {$x'\in\mathbb{R}^{N-1}$};
\node[anchor=west] at (0,5)
  {$x_{N}$};
\draw[->,help lines]
  (70:3cm) to[out=40,in=180] ++(2cm,20pt) node[right,text=black] {$I^{\ast}(r)$};
\draw[->,help lines]
  (70:4cm) to[out=40,in=180] ++(2cm,20pt) node[right,text=black] {$I^{\ast}(1)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you again, but I have a problem, when I'm compiling it the "-1, -r, r, 1" doesn't appear but what appear is "(-4,0), (-3,0), (0,3), (0,4)". can you help me why it's like that? @Gonzalo Medina

Answer (score 4):

Here is an initial response with tikz

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]

\draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) node[below]{$x'\in \mathrm{R}^{N-1}$};
\draw [->] (0,-0.1)--(0,1.5) node[right]{$x_N$};

\draw (1,0)node[below]{1} arc (0:180:1)node[below]{-1};

\def\radius{0.7}
\draw (\radius,0)node[below]{r} arc (0:180:\radius)node[below]{-r};
\draw (35:\radius) circle (0.2);
\begin{scope}
\draw[clip] (\radius,0)node[below]{r} arc (0:180:\radius)node[below]{-r};
\draw[fill=yellow]  (35:\radius) circle (0.2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To kill the time, I've tried to reproduce Gonzalo Medina's solution with MetaPost and LuaLaTeX. It wasn't that easy, but the most difficult was to find (more or less) matching colours in the standard SVG specifications (translated for MetaPost by the `mpcolornames` package), since I don't understand the coloring instructions of `tikz`. (I was too lazy to start reading the manual, but I'll be learning more soon, I promise :-))

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=2bp]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{luamplib}
    \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
input mpcolornames;
beginfig(1);
    numeric u, r, rho, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax; 
    u = 5cm; r = .75u; rho = .15u; z0 = u*(-.25, .25);
    xmax = -xmin = 1.25u; ymin = -.25u; ymax = 1.25u;
    path circle[], dome[], arrow[], intersect;
    dome1 = halfcircle scaled (2r); z1 = point 1 of dome1;
    dome2 = halfcircle scaled (2u);
    circle1 = fullcircle scaled (2rho) shifted z0; 
    circle2 = fullcircle rotated 90 scaled (2rho) shifted z1;
    intersect = buildcycle(dome1, circle2);


    fill dome2 -- cycle withcolor PeachPuff;
    fill dome1 -- cycle withcolor PaleTurquoise;
    fill intersect withcolor Salmon;
    for i = 1,2: draw dome[i]; draw circle[i]; endfor
    pickup pencircle scaled 3bp;
    drawdot z0 withpen pencircle scaled 3bp; 
    drawdot z1 withpen pencircle scaled 3bp;


    pickup pencircle scaled .5bp;
    z2 = point 0.7 of circle1;
    draw z0 -- z2;
    drawarrow (xmin, 0) -- (xmax, 0);
    drawarrow (0, ymin) -- (0, ymax); 
    label.bot("$x_0$", z0); label.urt("$x_0$", z1);
    label.top("$\rho$", .4[z0, z2]);
    label.bot("$-1$", (-u, 0)); label.bot("$1$", (u, 0));
    label.bot("$-r$", (-r, 0)); label.bot("$r$", (r, 0)); 
    label.rt("$x' \in \mathbb{R}^{N-1}$", (xmax, 0));
    label.lft("$x_N$", (0, ymax));

    arrow1 = (point 1.5 of dome1){dir 45} .. u*(.8, .9); 
    drawarrow arrow1 withcolor Gray; label.rt("$I^*(r)$", point 1 of arrow1);
    arrow2 = (point 1.5 of dome2){dir 40} .. u*(.9, 1.1); 
    drawarrow arrow2 withcolor Gray; label.rt("$I^*(1)$", point 1 of arrow2);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]