# Filter in PGFPlots by x coordinate value

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfkeys

I've been trying to springboard off of the answer I got from percusse [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232437/style-args-syntax-for-negative-not-except-to-make-this-cleaner-code), but I'm drowning in the PGFPlots manual.  I wanted to plot a smooth region in the middle, given the x coordinate values (instead of the x coordinate indices) but with

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    reduce to/.style args={every#1except between values#2and#3}{%
        /pgfplots/x filter/.append code={%
            \def\myswitch{1}%
            \ifx\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}>#2%
            %also tried pgfkeysgetvalue{/data point/x} which did not work 
                \ifx\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}<#3%
                    \def\myswitch{0}%
                \fi%
            \fi%
            \ifnum1=\myswitch%
                \pgfmathsetmacro\temp{int(mod(\coordindex,#1))}%
                    \ifnum0<\temp
                        \let\pgfmathresult\pgfutil@empty
                    \fi%
            \fi%
        }
    } 
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[reduce to=every 50 except between values 0 and 2]%
\addplot[samples=1501] {sin(deg(5*x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get the unexpected result of

[image: unexpectedResult]

...I would almost understand better if it did not compile.  Does anyone know what I should change to plot every point between the x values of 0 and 2?

Comment: Why do you use `\ifx` with `>` and `<`?

Comment: @Symbol1 probably because i don't know what i'm doing.  my desire is to make the < and > comparisons; the `ifx` was originally `\ifnum` for the coordinate index but i know i can't use that.  i also tried `ifdim` but i couldn't figure out how to get that to work

Comment: PGFPLOTS stores numbers in its own way which is not recognized by `\ifnum`. You should convert it back.

Comment: @Symbol1 i should change `\ifx` back to `\ifnum`?  i don't understand.  i'm no longer comparing integers, now i need to compare x coordinates w/ arguments - these will be floats (or need to be converted into lengths)

Comment: Please search `\ifpgfmathfloatcomparison` in PGFPLOTS manual. There is an example seems like what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These should work... finally

Please notice that inside an `x filter` there are two ways to get the current x-coordinate: via `#1` or `\pgfmathresult`. And the output should be stored at `\pgfmathresult`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=9]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    reduce to/.style args={every#1except between values#2and#3}{%
        /pgfplots/x filter/.code={%
            \let\pgfmathreserved\pgfmathresult
            \def\myswitch{1}%
            \pgfmathparse{##1>#2}%
            \ifpgfmathfloatcomparison
                \pgfmathparse{##1<#3}%
                \ifpgfmathfloatcomparison
                    \def\myswitch{0}%
                \fi%
            \fi%
            \let\pgfmathresult\pgfmathreserved
            \ifnum1=\myswitch%
                \pgfmathsetmacro\temp{int(mod(\coordindex,#1))}%
                \ifnum0<\temp
                    \let\pgfmathresult\pgfutil@empty
                \fi%
            \fi%
        }
    } 
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[reduce to=every 50 except between values 0 and 2]%
            \addplot[samples=1501] {sin(deg(5*x))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: that's almost exactly what i just did, using your suggestion to find the example in the manual.  but i get the same result and that plot indicates it's not working correctly : /

Comment: @aeroNotAuto I did it.

Comment: awesome! what are `\pgfmathreserved` and `##1`?  the first doesn't appear in the manual that i can see and the second appears but isn't explained.  i assume it has something to do with `\pgfmathresult` and not the typical first argument syntax `#1`

Comment: To your second question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42463/32374 http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/232636/32374

Comment: @aeroNotAuto To your first question: since `\pgfmathresult` is so fragile that any call of `\pgfmathparse` will destroy it, I would like to *reserve* the original value and load it back.