# What is the purpose of hash (#) as a special character sign?

Tags: macros

I understand the purpose of all special characters, `$`, `&`, `%`, `_`, `{`, `}`, `^`, `~`, and `\`, but just except for hash (`#`). When and why should it be used?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The character `#` (with category code 6) has two uses.

It denotes a parameter to a macro both in the parameter text and in the replacement text:

```
\def\foo#1{-#1-}
```

and in this context it should be followed by a digit from 1 to 9, with the restriction that the parameters must be numbered consecutively in the parameter text. Note that LaTeX automatically supplies the parameter text, so, for instance,

```
\newcommand{\foo}[3]{...}
```

ultimately reduces to

```
\def\foo#1#2#3{...}
```

There is a special usage for `#` in the parameter text: if `#` appears just before the opening brace, the last argument of the macro being defined will be delimited by the brace. You can see examples in the TeXbook or in TeX by Topic.

The second usage for `#` is in alignment preambles. The primitive `\halign` can be followed by `to <dimen>` or `spread <dimen>`, then a `{` should appear. What follows next is a sequence of chunks of the form `<u>#<v>` separated by `&` and ending with `\cr`, called the *alignment preamble*, whose purpose is to specify the tokens to be added to every subsequent entry in the table. The `#` represents the actual contents of a cell in the alignment. A typical alignment preamble can be

```
#\hfil&\hfil#\hfil&\hfil#\hfil&\hfil#\cr
```

which specifies four columns, with left alignment in the first, center alignment in the next two and right alignment in the fourth column.

In LaTeX, `tabular` is realized through `\halign`, the alignment preamble is automatically built from the mandatory argument to the environment.

Answer (score 17):

`#` is the macro parameter character, `#1` means macro parameter one, `#2` parameter two etc. If you want to use it as a character itself, use `\#` or change the catcode.

`\newcommand{\mymacro}[5]{%
 #1 #2 #3 #4 #5
}`

will use 5 macro arguments, available as `#1` to `#5`.

However, if there is a `\newcommand` within `\mymacro`, the macro parameter has to be doubled:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{%
  \newcommand{\myinnermacro}[1]{%
    Outer: #1

    Inner: ##1
  } 

  \myinnermacro{\textbf{#1}}
}


\begin{document}
\mymacro{\LaTeX\ is beautiful}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As can be seen from the screenshot, the content of `#1` is masked within of the inner macro and used as `##1` then.

The `#` property holds for `\def` and `\NewDocumentCommand` etc. too, of course.

**Edit**

Here is a bad example how to change the macro parameter character ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\catcode`#=11
\catcode`!=6


\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{%
  \newcommand{\myinnermacro}[1]{%
    Outer: !1

    Inner: !!1
  } 

  \myinnermacro{\textbf{!1}}
}


\begin{document}
\mymacro{\LaTeX\ is beautiful}
\end{document}
```

**Use it at your own risk** ;-)

Answer (score 14):

`#` is used in defining commands;

```
\newcommand\zzz[2]{this #1 and this #2.}
```

defines a command with two arguments such that

```
\zzz{a}{b}
```

expands to

```
this a and this b.
```

Comment: Stock answer? ;-)

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence there's not an answer posted to any question that couldn't be found in the archive of comp.text.tex over the last 30 years.