# Re-definition of a command inside an environment

Tags: environments, renewcommand

The redefinition of a command inside an environment works fine if the redefinition makes no use of the arguments,
but it fails if the arguments are used in the new definition.

the error message is :

*Illegal parameter number in definition of \inversion.*

(*inversion* is the involved environment, that is just defined, not used)

Here the two examples

```
%% FIRST
\documentclass{minimal} 
%
% a command with two arguments,
% the two argument are printed in natural order
\newcommand{\printtwoarg}[2]{TwoArg: #1 #2}
% the new command is redefined INSIDE a new environment, WITHOUT using the arguments 
\newenvironment{noprint}{\renewcommand{\printtwoarg}[2]{TwoArg: \relax}}{\relax}
%% the new command is redefined INSIDE a new environment: the arguments are printed in inverted order
%%\newenvironment{inversion}{\renewcommand{\printtwoarg}[2]{TwoArg: #2 #1}}{\relax}
%
\begin{document}
Using the new command:\\
\printtwoarg{TheFirst}{TheSecond}  \\
%
\begin{noprint}
Using the new command INSIDE the new environment:\\
\printtwoarg{TheFirst}{TheSecond}  \\
\end{noprint}
%
... and OUTSIDE again:\\
\printtwoarg{TheFirst}{TheSecond}  \\
%
\end{document}
```

and then

```
%% SECOND
\documentclass{minimal} 
%
% a command with two arguments,
% the two argument are printed in natural order
\newcommand{\printtwoarg}[2]{TwoArg: #1 #2}
% the new command is redefined INSIDE a new environment, WITHOUT using the arguments 
\newenvironment{noprint}{\renewcommand{\printtwoarg}[2]{TwoArg: \relax}}{\relax}
% the new command is redefined INSIDE a new environment: the arguments are printed in inverted order
\newenvironment{inversion}{\renewcommand{\printtwoarg}[2]{TwoArg: #2 #1}}{\relax}
%
\begin{document}
Using the new command:\\
\printtwoarg{TheFirst}{TheSecond}  \\
%
\begin{noprint}
Using the new command INSIDE the new environment:\\
\printtwoarg{TheFirst}{TheSecond}  \\
\end{noprint}
%
... and OUTSIDE again:\\
\printtwoarg{TheFirst}{TheSecond}  \\
%
\end{document}
```

First example works fine, second example fails.
The difference is the uncommented line where  the environment inversion is defined.

I really do not figure out if this is a difficult problem or a trivial problem !!

best regards and may thanks in advance

Battista Benciolini

Comment: Standard problem: every nesting of definitions needs to double the number of hashes. Use `##1` and `##2` instead of `#1` and `#2`.

Comment: Please, don't use `minimal` for examples. It's not meant for this purpose.

Comment: rallg edited the title of my question, making it more polite --
egreg posted a usefull recommendation --
campa answered the question in an essential and resolutive manner --
sincere thanks to everybody !

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was anwered in the comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pass variables to \renewcommand from within another command (\DeclareRobustCommand)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234644/how-can-i-pass-variables-to-renewcommand-from-within-another-command-declarer)

Comment: My improperly formulated self answer has been deleted. this is OK. I was preparing a better self-answer reporting the comment of campa, instead of simply citing it.  The comment really contains an essential and useful answer.  In the meantime the question has been closed. OK, I accept the decision. On the other hand I must ask what make my question off-topic.

Comment: I fully accept the closure of my question. On the other hand I would really appreciate if somebody could explain what makes my question off-topic.