# Ouch---my internal constants have been clobbered!---case 14

Tags: errors, texlive, linux, format-files

For an unknown to me reason, LaTeX started giving me this error: `Ouch---my internal constants have been clobbered!---case 14`. It throws the error even before it starts reading the file, so even if I run LaTeX or pdfLaTeX without any arguments I still get the error message and nothing else.

I took a look at this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67014/latex-gives-me-the-error-ouch-my-internal-constants-have-been-clobbered), but I'm not familiar with TeX inner workings at all, so I didn't find it helpful.

I tried completely uninstalling LaTeX and reinstalling it, but that didn't fix the error.

I'm running TeXLive on Linux Mint 14, kernel Linux 3.5.0-17-generic (x86_64).

Here's output from `dpkg --get-selections | grep tex`

```
biblatex                    install
dblatex                     install
gettext                     install
gettext-base                    install
jadetex                     install
latex-beamer                    install
latex-xcolor                    install
libdjvulibre-text               install
libexttextcat-1.0-0             install
libexttextcat-data              install
libgettextpo0:amd64             install
libgettextpo0:i386              install
liblatex-encode-perl                install
liblocale-gettext-perl              install
libptexenc1                 install
libtext-bibtex-perl             install
libtext-charwidth-perl              install
libtext-glob-perl               install
libtext-iconv-perl              install
libtext-wrapi18n-perl               install
luatex                      install
plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text          install
preview-latex-style             install
tex-common                  install
tex-gyre                    install
texlive                     install
texlive-base                    install
texlive-bibtex-extra                install
texlive-binaries                install
texlive-common                  install
texlive-doc-base                install
texlive-extra-utils             install
texlive-font-utils              install
texlive-fonts-extra             install
texlive-fonts-extra-doc             install
texlive-fonts-recommended           install
texlive-fonts-recommended-doc           install
texlive-generic-extra               install
texlive-generic-recommended         install
texlive-lang-cyrillic               install
texlive-latex-base              install
texlive-latex-base-doc              install
texlive-latex-extra             install
texlive-latex-extra-doc             install
texlive-latex-recommended           install
texlive-latex-recommended-doc           install
texlive-luatex                  install
texlive-math-extra              install
texlive-pictures                install
texlive-pictures-doc                install
texlive-pstricks                install
texlive-pstricks-doc                install
texlive-publishers              install
texlive-publishers-doc              install
texlive-science                 install
texlive-science-doc             install
texlive-xetex                   install
```

The only idea I have is that a package I installed recently called [Rivet](https://rivet.hepforge.org/), which I need for my research, might have messed with my latex installation.

Please, let me know if anybody has any idea as to how this issue could be fixed as I cannot use LaTeX on my computer anymore.

Thanks

Comment: try kpsewhich texmf.cnf or just search for files of that name using your operating system, it looks like you have one with settings incompatible with the TeX you are using.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle kpsewhich texmf.cnf found /home/ivanp/Physics/Rivet/local/share/Rivet/texmf/cnf/texmf.cnf

Here's what's inside:
    main_memory = 230000000 % words of inimemory available; also applies to inimf&mp
    extra_mem_top = 10000000 % extra high memory for chars, tokens, etc.
    extra_mem_bot = 10000000 % extra low memory for boxes, glue, breakpoints, etc.
    save_size = 150000 % for saving values outside current group
    stack_size = 150000 % simultaneous input sources

I don't know what to do with it though.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, I deleted /home/ivanp/Physics/Rivet/local/share/Rivet/texmf/ and latex runs now. Could you explain to me how this file was causing the error? Thanks.

Comment: in 25 years using Tex I've never seen that error:-) The answer that you linked to suggested that the problem was setting main_memory incorrectly in texmf.cnf.  main_memory = 230000000  does look suspiciously large (the default texlive 2013 is main_memory = 5000000)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: `if (mem_min<min_halfword) or (mem_max>=max_halfword) or (mem_bot-mem_min>max_halfword+1) then bad:=14;` - this is no problem with LuaTeX, btw.