# Texshop: Delete aux files in pdflatexmk engine

Tags: texshop

I'd like to enhance the pdflatexmk engine to delete the files afterwards. I'm coming from [Automatically "Trash Aux Files" after successful typesetting in TeXShop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88458/automatically-trash-aux-files-after-successful-typesetting-in-texshop), where the instruction is to write a Python file that does execute "pdftex", and then delete every other file ex-post.

However, I'm unaware in how I may call different texshop "engines". That is, instead of doing

```
command = '/usr/texbin/pdflatex ' + '--output-driver=/usr/texbin/xdvipdfmx ' +     OUTPUT_ARGUMENT + '"' + output_dir + '"' + ' ' + '"' + pdf_path + os.path.sep + tex_file + '"'
```

Since I'm saving my file in the `/Engine` folder, I thought I could simply

```
execfile("pdflatexmk.engine")
```

instead - But this gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Stuff/user/Library/TeXShop/Engines/pdflatexmk_del.py", line 43, in     <module>
    execfile("pdflatexmk.engine")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pdflatexmk.engine'
```

Comment: If you delete aux files, cross references will never resolve

Comment: I want to delete them after the final pdf was printed.

Comment: when you have finished you can do `rm *.aux` it doesn't make sense to get latexmk etc to do that as it can never know when you have finished editing and never want to run latex on that document again.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do. I try to write a Python script that first calls latexmk, and then removes all files. The part where it calls latexmk is where I have problems with.

Comment: I can't see when that is ever useful, that means every time to you edit the file and run latex it is going to take multiple runs to converge as the aux files are not there, this just makes processing much slower for no gain.

Comment: I am aware of the downsides, but my preferences differ from yours.

Comment: And you will have to disable the 'feature' every time you need to debug your code. (I'm assuming you don't just mean `.aux` files since it would be odd to want to delete those in particular and leave the rest.)

Comment: @cfr Don't worry, Texshop Engines show the "log" live, not the stored log file.

Comment: The `log` is not the only file you might need to look in to debug a problem!

Comment: In any case, the deletion is not immediately.

Comment: @FooBar Wouldn't calling `latexmk -c` do what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to say that during my whole experience on different stackexchange sites, I have never had such a negative experience w.r.t. a question; that is, a condescending "I know better than you want you should want" attitude.

Following is the simplest way to call texshop's pdflatexmk engine (if `__file__` is placed in the Engine folder):

```
import os, subprocess
# run pdflatexmk
engine = os.path.dirname(__file__)+'/pdflatexmk.engine'
file = pdf_path + os.path.sep + tex_file
command = '{0} "{1}"'.format(engine, file)
subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

And then, a safer way to delete is go with a blacklist, rather than a whitelist. Wait a bit, in case we want to re-run the compiler:

```
# wait a bit before delete
import time
time.sleep(360) # in seconds
# delete
file_plain = tex_file.split('.')[:-1][0]
print file_plain
del_list = ['log', 'aux', 'bbl', 'blg', 'fdb_latexmk', 'fls', 'synctex.gz', 'toc']
files = [pdf_path + os.path.sep + file_plain+'.'+l for l in del_list]
for file in files: os.remove(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Each engine is a shell script of its own, so probably the cleanest method to augment an existing engine is to add to the script.

What you want is to effectively call `pdflatexmk -c` after each successful run of `pdflatexmk`.

If you look at `pdflatexmk.engine` you'll see that the last line is:

```
"${LTMKBIN}"/latexmk -pdf -r "${LTMKEDIT}/latexmkrcedit" -r "${TSBIN}/pdflatexmkrc" ${localrc} "$1"
```

That's the nut of the whole script: calling `latexmk`.   To add commands that are executed only on successful completion of this line, add `&& <cmds>`.  So change the last line to:

```
"${LTMKBIN}"/latexmk -pdf -r "${LTMKEDIT}/latexmkrcedit" -r "${TSBIN}/pdflatexmkrc" ${localrc} "$1" && "${LTMKBIN}"/latexmk -c
```

Save that new engine as `pdflatexmk-c.engine` or something else you like, and restart TeXShop.

Then you can invoke this engine as the first line in your `.tex` file, as in:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk-c
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Foo}
\lipsum
\section{Bar}
\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

You'll see that `pdflatexmk` is run, running `pdflatex` a few times to get the generated references right, and then `pdflatexmk -c` is run, deleting the auxiliary files.