# Wildcard insertions in arara compile instructions

Tags: compiling, arara, bibunits

Using `arara` I would like to know whether wildcard instructions can be passed in the instructions.

I would like to have a dynamic compile of my bu*.aux files when I use bibunits, because as I comment out different sections, the number of files changes constantly.

Short of pointing arara to a custom script written to call `bibtex` in a for loop for all produced `bu*.aux` files, does arara have a feature/tool that I have overlooked that would permit this? I.e. I think this similar to this question:  [Arara rule to delete files with wildcard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164975/arara-rule-to-delete-files-with-wildcard) and [Deleting external/auxiliary files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24785/deleting-external-auxiliary-files/147748#147748), however, I am not sure whether the custom routine that provides user specified list of file extensions to clean, can be modified to work for the bibunits files.  I commented out the lines from the linked question in my MWE arara compile sequence that I am wondering about composing a rule to handle with similar logic.

```
% arara: xelatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: bibtex: { files: [ bu1, bu2] }
% !arara: bibtex: { files: [ bu*] }
% !clean: { extensions: [aux, bbl, bcl, blg <and more>] }
% arara: xelatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: xelatex: {synctex: yes}

\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[numbers,square,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}

\usepackage{bibunits}           % This package must be loaded after natbib
\defaultbibliographystyle{plain}% removes URL additions 
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section*{\bibname}\markboth{\leftmark}{\bibname}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{TopicOne.bib}
    @inproceedings{entry1,
        author = {Author name},
        address = {address},
        booktitle = {A book},
        title = {The book title},
        year = {2015},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{TopicTwo.bib}
    @article{entry2,
        author = {Author name},
        journal = {A Journal},
        title = {The article title},
        year = {2013},
    }
\end{filecontents*}

%--------------------BEGIN DOCUMENT----------------------
\begin{document}

\section{Topic One}
Real text that descibes the scope of the forthcoming bibliography would be here:
    \bibliography{TopicOne}
    \begin{bibunit}
        \nocite{*}
        \putbib[TopicOne]
    \end{bibunit}

\section{Topic Two}
Real text that descibes the scope of the forthcoming bibliography would be here for the next topic:
    \bibliography{TopicTwo}
    \begin{bibunit}
        \nocite{*}
        \putbib[TopicTwo]
    \end{bibunit}

\end{document}
```