# Texstudio pdflatex doesn't have -aux-directory Alternative

Tags: pdftex, texstudio

If checked in my command line but my version of pdflatex running on a university windows system doesn’t have the option -aux-directory. So I made a bat file moving the pdf from the output directory to the root folder. However this bat file just contains 1 command

```
move buildDIR\%1 .
```

Is there a way to do it without making a explicit bat file because now my pdflatex command looks like this.

```
pdflatex.exe  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=build  %.tex | "X://Data/Desktop/move.bat" "?m.pdf"
```

Is it possible to do something like this in 1 go?

```
pdflatex <options> | move buildDIR\?m.pdf .
```

I don't seem to get the above command to work correctly.

On a different example but same problem if in the pre-complication phase I want to make a new folder called buildDIR with one extra command can that be done without making a .bat file.

Comment: This answers gave me the solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24788