# A TikZ graph to teach LaTeX-related extensions

Tags: tikz-pgf, auxiliary-files, tex-general, teaching

This question is a follow up and complementary question to [File extensions related to LaTeX, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7770/140133)

Which is the main answer to some duplicates: [Use of different output files in LaTeX (pdflatex) [duplicate]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/152282/140133), [FIles produced by compiling LaTeX source code [duplicate]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207512/140133).

I was teaching a new student about the ***wonderful world of LaTeX*** when I discussed a little bit about all files extensions around LaTeX.

After explaining the basics about `.tex` and `.bib` and how a user should focus on these two extensions, I realized that there are much more (extension of) files than I knew.

I began to draw a graph in TikZ to visually represent the connections of all the extensions I remembered. But then I remembered there are (1) different compilers such as `pdflatex`, `LaTeX->dvips->ps2pdf` route (2) bibliography compilers such as `bibTeX`, `bibLaTeX` and  `biber`(3) class dependent files such as the ones from `beamer`.

> Could the community provide more graphs that elucidate the main relations between LaTeX environment extensions?

I let my first TikZ graph as an answer, it is a first attempt and illustration of the idea. I'm not sure if it is the most accurate or complete. I do hope it is clear to represent the main extensions and some variations.

*I even don't know if my TikZ file has been made with the best approach, suggestions about it are also welcome*.

I chose some *user levels* by different colors on the nodes.

> 0th: *Results*. Files to any computer user such as `.pdf`, `.html`, etc;
>
> 1st: *Beginner*. Create and edit `.tex` and `.bib`;
>
> 2nd: *Not so beginner*. Edit `.bst` or `.bbl`;
>
> 3rd: *I know some tricks*. Create `.sty`, `.cwl`, and edit `.cls`;
>
> 4th: *I know what I'm doing*. Create `.cls`, `.bst`, `.dtx`, `.ins`, etc and other extensions from 
>   scratch ;
>
> 5th: *Only machines allowed*. Files that no-human will create and should not edit such as `.aux`.

Anyone is free to change and to adapt it as it suits best.
Explanations of the extensions are not needed, since they are in the linked question.

> 1. Create a TikZ graph that represent the relationships between LaTeX extensions;
> 2. Keep all *language dependent text* together, so people around the world can reuse it fast;
> 3. Different colors for different user levels/experiences.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The main `.tex` file.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\input{fig_TikZ_graph_extensions}
\end{document}
```

The file `fig_TikZ_graph_extensions`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
[every path/.style={thick}]
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
% ---------- Language dependent texts
\newcommand{\infoto}{info to}; %p/ compilar
\newcommand{\compile}{compile}; % compilar
\newcommand{\navigate}{navigate}; % Navega\c{c}\~{a}o
\newcommand{\auxiliary}{auxiliary};
\newcommand{\error}{error}; % erro
\newcommand{\lists}{lists}; % listas
\newcommand{\watermark}{watermark}; % marca d'\draw{a}gua
\newcommand{\install}{install}; % instala\c{c}\~{a}o
% ----------
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={rectangle,thick,draw, blue}, shift={(0.5,0)}]
    \node (tex) at (-16,18.5) {
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \Large{.tex}
    \end{tabular}
    };
    \node (bib) at (-21.5,18.5) {
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \Large{.bib}
    \end{tabular}
    };
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={rectangle,thick,draw, cyan}, shift={(0.5,0)}]
    \node (pdf) at (-7,18.5) {
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \Large{.pdf}
    \end{tabular}
    };
    \node (html) at (-13,22) {
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \Large{.html}
    \end{tabular}
    };
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={rectangle,thick,draw,red}, shift={(0.5,0)}]
    \node (synctex) at (-11,17) {
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        \Large{.synctex.gz}
    \end{tabular}
    };
    \node (dvi) at (-13,20) {
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        \Large{.dvi}
    \end{tabular}
    };
    \node (ps) at (-9.5,20) {
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        \Large{.ps}
    \end{tabular}
    };
    \node (toc) at (-11,12.5) {
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \Large{.toc}
    \end{tabular}
    };
    \node (lof) at (-14,11.5) {
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \Large{.lof} \\
        \Large{.lot} \\
        \Large{.lol}
    \end{tabular}
    };
    \node (aux) at (-10.5,14) {
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \Large{.aux}
    \end{tabular}
    };
    \node (log) at (-20.5,13.5) {
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \Large{.log}
    \end{tabular}
    };
    \node (blg) at (-23,21) {
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \Large{.blg}
    \end{tabular}
    };
    \node (out) at (-12,11.5) {
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \Large{.out}
    \end{tabular}
    };
    \node (xwm) at (-16,11.5) {
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \Large{.xwm}
    \end{tabular}
    };
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={rectangle,thick,draw,orange!90!black}, shift={(0.5,0)}]
    \node (cls) at (-20,17.5) {
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \Large{.cls}
    \end{tabular}
    };
    \node (sty) at (-20,16) {
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \Large{.sty} \\
        \Large{.cwl}
    \end{tabular}
    };
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={rectangle,thick,draw,green!50!black}, shift={(0.5,0)}]
    \node (dtx) at (-23.5,16) {
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \Large{.dtx} \\
        \Large{.ins}
    \end{tabular}
    };
    \node (bst) at (-25.5,18.5) {
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \Large{.bst}
    \end{tabular}
    };
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={rectangle,thick,draw,violet}, shift={(0.5,0)}]
    \node (bbl) at (-19,21) {
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \Large{.bbl}
    \end{tabular}
    };
\end{scope}
% ===============
\begin{scope}[>={latex[blue]},
              every node/.style={rectangle},
              every edge/.style={draw=green!50!black,very thick}]
    \path [->] (cls) edge [bend right=+15] (tex);
    \path [->] (sty) edge [bend right=+25] (tex);
    \path [->] (bbl) edge [bend right=+00] node[above right]{\infoto}(tex);
    % --------------
    \path [<->] (bst) edge[bend right=+00] node[midway, above]{\infoto} node[midway, below]{bib\TeX} (bib);
\end{scope}
% ----------
\begin{scope}[>={latex[blue]},
              every node/.style={rectangle},
              every edge/.style={draw=red,very thick}]
    \path [->] (bib) edge[bend right=-10] node[left]{\error} (blg);
    \path [->] (bib) edge node[left = 2mm]{bib\TeX} node[right = 2mm]{bib\LaTeX} (bbl);
    \path [->] (tex) edge[bend right=+00] node[above]{pdflatex} node[below]{\compile} (pdf);
    \path [->] (tex) edge [bend right=-25] node[below right]{\error} (log);
    \path [->] (tex) edge [bend right=-25] node[above left]{htlatex} (html);
\end{scope}
% ----------
\begin{scope}[>={latex[blue]},
              every node/.style={rectangle},
              every edge/.style={draw=purple,very thick}]
    \path [->] (dtx) edge[bend right=+00] node[midway, above]{\install} (sty);
    \path [->] (tex) edge node[below,rotate=90]{\watermark} (xwm);
    \path [->] (tex) edge[bend right=+00] node[below,rotate=105]{\lists} (lof);
    \path [->] (tex) edge node[above right,rotate=-40]{\auxiliary} (aux);
    % --------------
    \path [->] (tex) edge[bend right=+00] (toc);
    \path [->] (tex) edge[bend right=+00] (out);
    % --------------
    \path [<->] (tex) edge [bend right=+10] node[above right]{\navigate} (synctex);
    \path [<->] (synctex) edge[bend right=+10] node[above left]{\navigate} (pdf);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[>={latex[blue]},
              every node/.style={rectangle},
              every edge/.style={draw=violet,very thick,dashed}]
    \path [<->] (bib) edge[bend right=+00] (tex);
    \path [->] (tex) edge[bend right=+00] node[above left]{latex} (dvi);
    \path [->] (dvi) edge[bend right=+00] node[above]{dvi2ps} (ps);
    \path [->] (ps) edge[bend right=+00] node[above right]{ps2pdf} (pdf);
\end{scope}
% ----------
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is the *colorful* result.

[image]

The color legend is:

> 0th: *Results*, cyan;
>
> 1st: *Beginner*, blue;
>
> 2nd: *Not so beginner*, violet;
>
> 3rd: *I know some tricks*, orange;
>
> 4th: *I know what I'm doing*, green;
>
> 5th: *Only machines allowed*, red.

Comment: "auxiliar" is an [archaic form](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/auxiliar) of "auxiliary" (in fact, my spell checker flags "auxiliar").  I believe that "auxiliary" is used more frequently in modern LaTeX terminology.

Comment: nicely done! I noticed there were a few nodes where you had `tabular` with just one entry. I wondered if these were necessary?

Comment: @L.F., indeed, totally my mistake. It is a _false cognate_ between English and Portuguese [auxiliar == auxiliary](https://www.linguee.com.br/portugues-ingles/search?source=auto&query=auxiliar) and the difference is one extra letter, so it is common not to realize the difference. I edited my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @cmhughes, they _were_ necessary when I started the code, there _were_ more than one extension per node. Now they _are_ not necessary anymore. I just copied and pasted content inside them without worrying. A clean and revised file should certainly not have them. Thanks.

Comment: Nice. Though I am under the impression that `.aux` and `.toc` are read by consecutive runs of latex. The graph does not reflect that.

Comment: Hi @Hermann, to reflect that, should an arrow point to `.toc` from `.aux`? And adding some info on the arrow?