Which types of files can be safely deleted from a finsihed project?
I wrote a book with LaTeX and it's done (in case you are interested, the title is Twice as Weird: A Memoir about Twice Exceptionality).  As it does, LaTeX generated a lot of files, especially because there are many drafts. I want the final .tex file to be modifiable and to run, in case I want to write a revision.
Which files can I safely delete? There are .bbl, .bak, .synctex, .tdo and .toc files, in addition to the .tex files that I know I need.

bbl is generated by bibtex (or biber) synctex is generated by tex .toc is generated by latex. they can all go, .bak is probably your editor backup that won't be re-generated but you can delete if you have backed up the sources elsewhere. .tdo I don't know, will be some package specific file i would guess

Except for the final document, If you didn't create it with an editor, you can delete it.  TeXnicCenter has a "Clean Project" menu option which will delete all the temporary files, listing them all first.

See this discussion about methods of cleaning the folder here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24787/233251 .

Thanks @Iacobus1983 .  That's very helpful.  That question didn't show up when I was typing in mine.

You can also look at it differently: you have finished the book, so you are probably not going to look in the folder that contains all those files very often. So, they will not bother you, and you can leave them as they are. When you decide to write a revision, you will need to (automatically) regenerate the files anyway, so why not keep them now? That might even save a bit of compiling time, for example when your revision doesn't add new references then you don't need to run BibTeX/Biber to regenerate the .bbl.

Thanks @Marijn.  The only reason is that having all those files can make it hard to find other files in the same directory, but maybe I can move things around.

@Marijn If you use Biblatex, though, you'll almost certainly get an error from the existing .bbl and have to delete anyway, so arguably deleting Biblatex/Biber files will increase compilation time.

Put your sources into a git repository, run git clean -n to see what git would remove, if you're fine with the selection run git clean -f. Only the things you initially create should be checked into git, everything else will be derived. git will remove everything else since it's not checked in. If you want to keep any created PDF running git clean -e '*.pdf' -f would do that.

Except what you directly included as code/text sources   (.tex, .bib, and maybe a .csv or whatever ...)  or external images (.png, .jpg and .pdf or .eps), anything else can be safely deleted. Move that files to a new directory, make the backup, and test that you can recompile the new directory, to be sure that you do not forget to pick some source file.  Then you can erase your dirty working directory.
