# Where is there a registry of intermediate TeX file extensions?

Tags: auxiliary-files, naming

I'm just about to embark on a new package which will need to write a single temporary file (similar to .aux etc.).

The temporary file is, in fact, a specialised bibliography, but I want to avoid possible conflicts, so I can't, for example, call it `\jobname.bib`; I might call it, perhaps, `\jobname.gitlog.bib`, but I'd prefer a simpler name, such as `\jobname.gll`.

Hence the question: I'd like to see if `.gll` is already *taken,* find an alternative if so, and register my interest.

Comment: I don't think there's anything like that.

Comment: You could also pick a default extension and provide the user a way to change it if they need to, via a package option.

Answer (score 5):

Many years ago I started to put something like this together:

https://github.com/wspr/latex-auxfiles

It's sadly neglected, but might be of help.

Comment: Also relevant, but probably also not a complete list: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/TeX.gitignore

Comment: see also [Which auxiliary LaTeX files should be ignored by Version Control Software?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17845/4918) here on TeX.SX.

Answer (score 2):

The collaborative effort on a `.gitignore` file for TeX might be a good starting point: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/TeX.gitignore

Comment: Sorry @Adam: I've only seen [your comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278399/where-is-there-a-registry-of-intermediate-tex-file-extensions/278443#comment670517_278425) after adding my answer...